# IndexError wrong error Python

Tags: python

I am deleting phantom files we have in Slack. Below is my script. I am getting an IndexError list index out of range error. Can someone provide assistance on what I am doing wrong.

```
import Slacker
import sys
import time
from datetime import timedelta, datetime


def main(token, weeks=4):
    slack = Slacker(token)
    total = slack.files.list(count=1).body['paging']['total']
    num_pages = int(total/1000.00 + 1)
    print("{} files to be processed, across {} pages".format(total, num_pages))
    files_to_delete = []
    ids = [] 
    count = 1
    for page in range(num_pages):
        print ("Pulling page number {}".format(page + 1))
        files = slack.files.list(count=1000, page=page+1).body['files']
        for file in files:
            print("Checking file number {}".format(count))
            if file['id'] not in ids:
                ids.append(file['id'])
                if datetime.fromtimestamp(file['timestamp']) < datetime.now() - timedelta(weeks=weeks):
                    files_to_delete.append(file)
                    print("File No. {} will be deleted".format(count))
                else:
                    print ("File No. {} will not be deleted".format(count))
            count+=1

    print("All files checked\nProceeding to delete files")
    print("{} files will be deleted!".format(len(files_to_delete)))
    count = 1
    for file in files_to_delete:
        print("Deleting file {} of {}".format(count, len(files_to_delete)))
        slack.files.delete(file_=file['id'])
        print("Deleted Successfully")
        count+=1

    return count-1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        token = sys.argv[1:]
    except IndexError:
        print("Usage: python file_deleter.py api_token\nPlease provide a value for the API Token")
        sys.exit(2)

    main(token[0])
```

It gives an error on the last line main (token[0]).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aqureshi/Desktop/Programming/Slacker.py", line 50, in <module>
    main(token[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: and how do you execute the program? I presume you are passing some arguments?

Comment: You should say how you are running the file.... `sys.argv[1:]` means it expects command line arguments

Comment: This script has been forwarded to me by a senior developer. I thought it should work but I know I am missing elements here. If you can highlight those elements I would appreciate it.

Comment: If you're running this in an IDE (Eclipse, PyCharm, etc), you'll want to add input arguments to the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve the error like so, but that'll just tell you how you need to actually run this file.

In other words, **Please provide a value for the API Token**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        token = sys.argv[1:]
        main(token[0])
    except IndexError:
        print("Usage: python file_deleter.py api_token\nPlease provide a value for the API Token")
        sys.exit(2)
```

Something like `Desktop\> python Slacker.py xxxxAPI_TOKENxxxx`

I might re-write that try-except to actually validate the length of the arguments, though

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python file_deleter.py api_token\nPlease provide a value for the API Token")
        sys.exit(2)

    token = sys.argv[1:]
    main(token[0])
```

Comment: Thanks Cricket_007 let me see how far I can get with this. I am new to Python and learning thanks to kind developers like you guys. Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Nominally you could fix the problem by moving `main(token[0])` inside the try/except block. But that is problematic because any other `IndexError` in the program could be mistakenly reported as a command-usage problem. Better to check the input parameter explicitly. It also gives you a chance to check against common help flags.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2 or sys.argv[1] in ('-h', '--help', '/?'):
        print("Usage: python file_deleter.py api_token\nPlease provide a value for the API Token")
        sys.exit(2)
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Expecting this

```
token = sys.argv[1:]
```

To throw an exception is erroneous. It never will, it will just go on to return an empty list if `sys.argv` itself is only length 1. Then

```
main(token[0])
```

Is your `IndexError`

Instead check the length of your `sys.argv` variable. It should be at least 2 for there to be 1 or more arguments.

```
import sys

def main(x):
    print(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Usage: python file_deleter.py api_token\nPlease provide a value for the API Token")
        sys.exit(2)

    main(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Too many parameters is also bad. Better to check for 2 explicitly.